# Knockout.js update values from mysql database

Tags: mysql, ajax, knockout.js

Let's assume that I have 3 computers that write to a mysql database based on whether they are online or offline every 5 minutes.

I display this information on a website in a simple html table and read the mysql database with php.

The output goes something like this:

```
<table>
    <th>Computer portfolio</th>
    <tr>
        <td>Computer Name</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Last Connected</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Computer 1</td>
        <td>Okay</td>
        <td>2013-07-10 00:15:25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Computer 2</td>
        <td>Down</td>
        <td>2013-07-08 00:15:25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Computer 3</td>
        <td>Okay</td>
        <td>2013-07-10 00:17:25</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The php code is really easy and is just returning a select * from db then iterating through the array.

My question is simply, how do I incorporate knockout to reload the results from the DB every 5 minutes to refresh the items on the page.

Comment: First, re-write your table using knockout observables. Second, call a services every 5 minutes to get the new data & refresh the observables

Comment: @AndrewWalters Can you give me an example of how this might work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/bLDom)

```
function getJSON(callback) {
    // Get an array from the server
    // callback(data)
}
```

Create a view model with an observable array.  Then make a refresh method that pulls data, and overrides the observable.  Because all items in the array are dependant on the root array, there's no need for them to be observable.

```
function ViewModel(){
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.refresh = function(){
    getJSON(function(data){
      self.items(data);
      console.log(data);

    });
  }
```

Refresh once, and then again at the desired interval, e.g., 5 minutes.

```
  self.refresh();
  setTimeout(self.refresh, 5 * 60 * 1000);
}

ko.applyBindings(app = new ViewModel);
```

---

jQuery provides [very easy AJAX methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/), such as [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

```
function getJSON(callback) {
    $.getJSON('tabledata.php', callback);
}
```

---

Also, there's a plugin called [Live](https://github.com/thelinuxlich/knockout.live.plugin), which syncs data in real time between multiple clients.  However it depends on NodeJS, so it may not be a good solution to you (mostly posting it here for future-googlers.

Comment: Well, I have this only partially written.   I'd love some suggestions on background reading or other similar projects that I could look at.

Comment: I gave a jQuery example.  It's probably a bit extreme to pull the enter jQuery library into your app for that, but it depends on your performance needs (usually a half a second longer to load).  You can find other methods by searching "get ajax json without jQuery".